# Group time values by day/week/month/year

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am using PostgeSQL `copy` command to insert values into table. One of the column is of type `time`. 
How can I group these time values into day/week/month/year ?

sample table format:

```
Time    , No, DE, Slot, Usage    , RAID Group No, Type     ,  Busy Rate (%)
12:08:38,  0,  0,    0, Data Disk,             0, 600GB SAS,  14549
12:08:38,  1,  0,    1, Data Disk,             0, 600GB SAS,  14567
12:09:39,  2,  0,    2, Data Disk,             0, 600GB SAS,  14350
```

The objective is to perform time series analysis of storage performance metrics through graphs.Unfortunately, the performance data collected from storage servers do not record the "timestamp" values in the csv file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you bring the expected result sample?

Comment: The resultant graph is expected to be similar to the below image with storage metrics like IOPS, Mbps on Y axis and DateTime format on X axis: http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/images/slider/jquery-flot-time-series-chart.jpg

Comment: You don't have any days anywhere in sight, you only have time-of-day values. You can't group by something you don't have.